# Test case for a set of questions

Tags: selenium, c#

I have this scenario where my page has set of questions and the answers are in radio buttons **Yes** and **No**. There are around 7-8 yes/no questions. I want to design a test case using C# so that everytime random responses are selected by the program and the final outcome is recorded. Here is test case code till now:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace Test1
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BS1T1FailCasePage3
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var driver = new ChromeDriver(@"E:\Series\Drivers");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://qmloansdev.azurewebsites.net");
            var xpathElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='SSN']"));
            xpathElement.SendKeys("1234");
            var xpathElement1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[contains(text(),'January')]"));
            xpathElement1.Click();
            var xpathElement10 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[text()='1']"));
            xpathElement10.Click();

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='Terms']/div[3]/section/label[1]/i")).Click(); //Checkbox1
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='Terms']/div[3]/section/label[2]/i")).Click(); //Checkbox2
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='Terms']/div[3]/section/label[3]/i")).Click(); //Checkbox3
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='frmGatekeeper']/fieldset[4]/div/div[1]/button")).Click(); //Button to next page

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='Refinance[SB1]']")).Click(); //Dropdown option 1
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//option[@value='Purchase']")).Click(); //Dropdown option 2

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='frmQuestionnaire']/fieldset[2]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/label[2]/i")).Click(); //Radio button option = Yes
            //driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='frmQuestionnaire']/fieldset[3]/section[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/label[2]/i")).Click(); //Radio button option = No

            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='Question03_SubQuestions']/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/label/i")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='frmQuestionnaire']/button")).Click();

            var loggedInHeader = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(".//*[@id='heading']"));

            String p = "Initial Borrower Survey";

            if (loggedInHeader.Text.Contains(p))
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "Test Passed.");
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.IsFalse(loggedInHeader.Displayed, "Test Failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know how can I do this!!!!! I really can't figure out how randomly selecting some options can be done in a C# unit test case.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Please show us your attempt and the bits you have working, like doing it without the random piece, say click them all or all in order, can you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can designate "Yes" radio button selection as 1 and "No" radio button selection as 0.

For each question,

```
Random rand = new Random();

if (rand.NextDouble() >= 0.5)
    click Yes;
else
    click No;
```

You should get a 50% of chance for an answer to be randomly selected.